# python ImportError: No module name engines.extras.download_datos_desambiguar

Tags: python, file, import, lucene, importerror

I have the following hierarchy

- src(folder)

  - engines(folder)

    - ProcesosContinuos.py
    - extras(folder)

      - download_datos_disambiguar(folder)

        - news_Lucene.py

In `ProcesosContinuous.py` I am importing news_Lucene.py like this

```
from engines.extras.download_datos_desambiguar import news_Lucene
```

But on running this, it gives me an error:

```
ImportError: No module name engines.extras.download_datos_desambiguar
```

I tried many tweaks with the import line but nothing helps me. I tried looking over many SO posts related to this but nothing seems to be what I'm looking for.

I have also tried creating a shell script in the folder `engines` with the following code

```
python ~/code/4dlife_repo/4dbatch/src/engines/extras/download_datos_desambiguar/news_Lucene.py
```

and this works fine. So there is no problem with the `news_Lucene.py` code or its related paths. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any `__init__.py` files in your folders? Adding these files (they can be empty) will turn your folders into actual Python packages.

Comment: Yes I do have it. It is under engines>stats>__init__.py. However, it is empty.

Comment: You need `__init__.py` files in every single folder that you try to use as a Python package. So you'll need one in `extras` and `download_datos_disambiguar` too.

Comment: but when I try to access a function in `news_Lucene.py`, it can't recognize it. It says `AtrributeError:'module' object has no attribute indexing` where `indexing()` is the function in `news_Lucene.py`

Comment: I am accessing `indexing()` like this `news_Lucene.indexing()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to add `__init__.py` in every folder in order to use it as a Python package.

Answer (score -2):

Normally, i would print sys.path out to see if the root folder is there. In your case i think`~/code/4dlife_repo/4dbatch/src` should be in sys.path.